# How to report spammy Facebook accounts?

Tags: facebook, spam-prevention

As a group administrator, I frequently (several times a day) receive requests to join the group from fake accounts, usually camping an elderly person, that will, once accepted, start posting messages (or worst, commenting on every existing post) about offering loans and other financial services. This has been going on for months.

What is the most efficient way to report such accounts? The issue with the report function of Facebook is that there is no clear "spam" category. When you try to report an user, you first have the choice to block it, submit a report or indicate that this is an old account of yours. If you choose to report it, you can either report the content or report the account. If you choose the latter, you're presented with these options:

[image: report options]

As you can see, there is no obvious choice. Until then, I have been using the "fake account" options with "other" as a sub-option, but the "annoying person" with "send spam" (albeit this seems to be about direct message spamming) is also a possible choice, as is reporting the content instead of the account.

**What is the best way to deal with automated fake accounts posting spam?**

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be 4 options: fake name, annoying, fake account, and business. These accounts are probably fake (but that's difficult to prove) but definitely business (and also annoying but I doubt if that would be effective).

If you're in for some exploration and have enough spam accounts to report, choose the option randomly from the most plausible options (I'd say 3: fake name, fake account and business). Keep track of which option was selected and how long it took for the account to stop spamming your group. You'll then be able to test which option is most efficient...